# Picking Multiple Values from String

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have data like the sample data below, and I'm trying to pattern match and parse it to create something like the output data.  The idea is, if I have a string value that contains "Aggr(" then parse the "stuff" in the parenthesis and the parse the following "something" that follows the comma before the next parenthesis.  Is there a slick way to do this with like regex, or is it going to require a couple of loops?

```
Sample Data:

SampleDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom',"words Aggr(stuff),something1)"],['bob',"Morewords Aggr(Diffstuff),something2"]],columns=['ReportField','OtherField'])

Sample Output:

OutputDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom',"words Aggr(stuff),something1",'stuff', 'something1'],['bob',"Morewords Aggr(Diffstuff),something2",'Diffstuff','something2']],columns=['ReportField','OtherField','Part1','Part2'])
```

Comment: Take a look at https://regex101.com it allows you to test python regexps online. I am sure you can do it well with regexps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` to capture pattern in the string and convert each into a column:

```
pd.concat([
        SampleDf, 
        SampleDf.OtherField.str.extract(r"Aggr\((?P<Part1>.*?)\),(?P<Part2>[^\(]*)", expand=True)
    ], axis=1)

#   ReportField                             OtherField      Part1        Part2
#0          tom           words Aggr(stuff),something1      stuff   something1
#1          bob   Morewords Aggr(Diffstuff),something2  Diffstuff   something2
```

*regex* `Aggr\\((?P<Part1>.*?)\\),(?P<Part2>[^\\(]*)` captures two patterns you needed (with one being `Aggr\\((?P<Part1>.*?)\\)` named *part1*: the content in the first parenthesis after *Aggr*, another being `,(?P<Part2>[^\\(]*)` named *part2*: the pattern after the comma following the first pattern before the next parenthesis).

Comment: Thank you!! This is just what I was looking for, much simpler than a loop.  Very cool, very slick.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.extractall with regex pattern matching

```
SampleDf[['Part1', 'Part2']]=SampleDf.OtherField.str.extractall('\((.*)\),(.*)').reset_index(drop = True)
```

You get

```
    ReportField OtherField                              Part1       Part2
0   tom         words Aggr(stuff),something1            stuff       something1
1   bob         Morewords Aggr(Diffstuff),something2    Diffstuff   something2
```