# Pattern match and create new string based on number at end of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like the sample data below, where I have string values that have a number at the end of the string. I would like to pattern match the string inside the parenthesis and use the number at the end to indicate the order old field value occurs in a new string concatenated with `"/"`. The output example is below, any suggestions are welcome.

Sample Data:

```
SampleDf=pd.DataFrame([['sum(field1)'],['count(field2)'],['Sum(value1)'],['Max(field3)']],columns=['ReportField'])
```

Sample Output:

```
OutputDf=pd.DataFrame([['sum(field1)/count(field2)/Max(field3)'],['Sum(value1)']],columns=['ratio'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070416/picking-multiple-values-from-string), you could extract the string and the number from the parenthesis as separate columns, sort by the number, group by the string and then aggregate the original field by joining them with `/`:

```
(pd.concat([
    SampleDf,
    SampleDf.ReportField.str.extract(r"\((.*?)(\d+)\)", expand=True)
], axis=1).sort_values(1)
 .groupby(0).ReportField.agg({'ratio': "/".join}).reset_index(drop=True))
​
#   ratio
#0  sum(field1)/count(field2)/Max(field3)
#1  Sum(value1)
```